# SSIS Data Flow Items and SSIS Contol Flow Items Tab missing in Visual Studio 2013 from _Choose Toolbox Items_

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, business-intelligence

I have a VS 2013 installed, and successfully installed "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2013"

All BI project templates are OK, all toolbox items are OK. I also can create a new Integration Services project, and toolbox correctly shows all the SSIS out of the box items.

.

[image: All OK, BI seems to installed]

.

However when I try to add a new custom Toolbox item and choose Tools/Choose Toolbox Items the dialog has no "SSIS Data Flow Items" and "SSIS Contol Flow Items" tabs.

.

[image: Tabs are missing]

.

Because of the tabs are missing, I can not add custom component to my SSIS Data Flow Items tab. The following picture is from a tutorial, it shows what I am expecting to see:

[image]

I consider the missing tabs a symptom of something went wrong, but not insist to see the tabs, if there is any alternative way to add custom component to the SSIS Data Flow toolbox. But the most relaxing would be if the tabs were appeared...

Btw I have two machine with this exactly same symptoms, a 2012 Server and a Win 7 box.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the steps [here](http://jessekraut.wordpress.com/ssis-2012-custom-component-install-guidelines/) for SQL Server 2012 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the complaints custom component developers for SSIS had was that installation of their product (to the GAC and Program Files) still required the manual adding of them, as your final screenshot depicts.

2012+ no longer has this requirement. Instead, by virtue of a DLL being correctly built for that specific version of SSIS, "it will just show up" TM

I'm not finding the blog references but there were announcements about the change

"It just works" was already claimed

Comment: Answer is correct, but it's really hard to get custom task now.

Comment: @AbhishekTomar Sounds like you have a question? Ping me if you post a question to SO - happy to see what I still remember about custom componentry for SSIS

Comment: Same question, My component is not showing in SSIS toolbar .. VS2017 :(

Comment: @AbhishekTomar Component from a commercial vendor or internally produced? If vendor, which one and have you confirmed you have the correct version of the product along with the version of SSIS you are targeting?

Comment: This is custom component created by me for testing... i will share my code on GitHub.